# I'm unable to install pyautogui : KeyError: 'IMPORT_STAR'

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyautogui

No matter what I try it gives me always the same error :

```
...
File "C:\Users\leons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
          from .command.build_exe import BuildEXE as build_exe
        File "C:\Users\leons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\command\build_exe.py", line 13, in <module>
          from cx_Freeze.freezer import Freezer
        File "C:\Users\leons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 30, in <module>
          from .finder import ModuleFinder
        File "C:\Users\leons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 33, in <module>
          IMPORT_STAR = opcode.opmap["IMPORT_STAR"]
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      KeyError: 'IMPORT_STAR'
```

Can anyone help with this one ?

I tried `pip install pyautogui` and all of it's variations.
I also tried to install older versions of pyautogui.
I reinstalled all dependencies, updated and upgraded everything.
Tried it in a admin terminal and in a regular terminal.

I am on windows not linux

Comment: It's the 'pytweening' library that causes the issue

Comment: error shows problem with module `cx_Freeze`, not with `PyAutoGUI`, nor `pytweening`

Comment: I solved it by installing a older version of pytweening and then installing pyautogui without it.

Comment: you could describe it below as answer. And later you can accept (and upvote) your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

cx_Freeze and dependencies (cx_Logging, Lief) are not declared compatible with Python 3.12 (yet!) and do not provide a wheels for it.

But, you can test the latest development build:

`pip install --upgrade --pre --extra-index-url https://marcelotduarte.github.io/packages/ cx_Freeze`

For conda-forge the command is:

`conda install -y --no-channel-priority -S -c https://marcelotduarte.github.io/packages/conda cx_Freeze`

**Reference**:

[#issue_2117](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/2117): By Owner: [marcelotduarte](https://github.com/marcelotduarte) commented on Oct 30, 2023

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing a older version of pytweening and then installing pyautogui without it.
It seems to be a issue with libraries updating resulting in conflicts